# $P(\alpha) = \alpha^3$ and $P(\beta) = \beta^3$, find the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$

Tags: polynomials

The statement of the problem is:

When polynomial $P(x)$ is divided by $x-\alpha$, the remainder is $\alpha^3$. When it is divided by $x-\beta$, the remainder is $\beta^3$. Find the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$.

I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Well...as a start, write $P(x)=Q(x)\times (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)+R(x)$.  What degree is $R(x)$?  How many values of $R(x)$ do you need to know to determine it?  How many values can you find?

Comment: I think you need $\alpha\ne \beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remainder is of the form $ ax+b$. You need to find $a$ and $b$.
So we use the division algorithm : $$P(X)= Q(x) ( x-\alpha)(x- \beta) + ax+b$$. Put in the equation $ x= \alpha, x= \beta$ and solve the simultaneous equation to find $a$ and $b$.